# Magento rwd theme not working in Responsinator

Tags: magento-1.9

I have install magneto 1.9 and i am using rwd theme it working fine in mobile but not working in Responsinator.
Responsinator showing only white screen.
Any idea what i do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u solved?? this???

Answer (score 0):

System > Configuration > Admin > Security

Need to change setting in Allow Magento Frontend to run in frame **"Only from same domain" to "Enable"**